# Array of children present in node of firebase realtime database in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to think of a possible logic to get my desired output in Java, Android Studio. Can anyone please help me with any possible outcome?
My desired output is of a String array containing as follows:

```
Strs[0]="neet"
Strs[1]="jee mains"
```

I want to get a String array of a node from the firebase realtime database when the children of the nodes vary. I am hereby attaching the image from the database for clear understanding:

[image]

Comment: Means you want to show only JEE and NEET ? instead of it's data inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to retrieve the node name you can use this code :

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference courceRef = database.getReference().child("Cources");
List<String> cources = ArrayList<String>();
courceRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        cources.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            cources.add(snap.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```